# change specific span text based on array value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

I have some input hidden value in jquery array and i want to change the value of span based on array. Here is the [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/webdevanuj/occ624t9/).

Now what i want is when 0 is triggered in an alert box then my current `span` text will change with some text, not all `span` text like at this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the text you want like so:

```
$('input[name="quantity"][value="0"]').parent().find('button span').html('some text');
```